# How to get a Python function to display an IPython widget

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I want to call a function that displays a widget in a Jupyter notebook.

However if I do something like this:

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets

def show_widget():
    progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0, min=0, max=100)
    display(progress)

show_widget()
```

The only output I get is `A jupyter widget.`... just that text, not the actual widget. Any ideas?

**Note:** I can display widgets just fine if I create and display them outside of a function... just doesn't work when I call a function that's supposed to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was likely some issue of incompatibility between certain components of my Jupyter setup. So I uninstalled/re-installed my setup and now this works fine.

Check out this [github question](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892) if you have an issue like this.